# error on overriding a bool abstract method

Tags: c#

I'm not understanding why there is this error in my derived class to overide a method boolean

```
        public class HotRod : Racer
{
    private bool blower = true || false;

    public HotRod();


    public HotRod(string racerName, int racerSpeed, Engine _engine);
    {
        racerName = name;
        racerSpeed = speed;
        Engine = engine;    
    }

    public override bool IsDead()
    {
        Engine engine1 = new Engine();
        Engine = engine1;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        rnd.NextDouble();
        bool dead = false;

        if (racerSpeed > 50 && rnd.NextDouble() > 0.6)
            if (engine1.horsePower < 300 && blower == true)
                dead = false;
            else
                dead = true;

        else if (racerSpeed > 100 && rnd.NextDouble() > 0.4)

            if (engine1.horsePower >= 300 && blower == true)
                dead = true;
            else
                dead = false;
        else
            dead = false;

        return dead;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string output;

        output = "\n============ HotRod Information ============";
        output += "\n\t              Racer's Name:\t" + racerName;
        output += "\n\t               Car's Speed:\t" + carSpeed;
        output += "\n\t          Engine Cylinders:\t" + engineCylinders;
        output += "\n\t         Engine Horsepower:\t" + engineHorsePower;
        output += "n\t               Racer's Type:\t" + racerType;
        output += "n\t          Racer with Blower:\t" + carBlower;
        output += "n\t             Still Working?:\t" + IsDead;

        return output;
    }
}
```

The error is too the   bool  and says Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

can I get any help with this

Comment: Post your full code.. including the abstract class.

Comment: You have a syntax error, but it is no visible on the code you pasted, we'll need to see more.

Comment: `public HotRod(string racerName, int racerSpeed, Engine _engine);` <-- that (invalid location for a semicolon)

Comment: Thanks that fixed everything by removing that semicolon on that class.  Now I got a couple more errors but I will just ask another question to see if I can get some help to fix them

Comment: Also this one `public HotRod();` <-- remove this semi-colon and use `{}`.

Comment: VS should be highlighting your error with a red underline...

Answer (score 1):

Is IsDead() in the abstract class is virtual method?

Override must be virtual method.