# Abstract class problems in C#

Tags: c#

I got an abstract class that has an abstract method that is based on to 2 other derived classes. I got an error that says Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct with the redline under     bool     . I know that there should be more code in the `{}` braces just I need it to ask if the car still runs and that is what the     `IsDead()`     is all about

```
namespace Car Racer
{
    public abstract class Racer
    {
        private string racerName;
        private int racerSpeed;
        private Engine engine;

        public Racer()
        {

        }

        public Racer(string _name, int _speed, Engine _engine)
        {
            racerName = name;
            racerSpeed = speed;
            Engine = engine;
        }

        public string Engine()
        {}
            private int cylinders = 0;
            private int engineHorsePower = 0;
        }

        public abstract bool IsDead();

    }
}
```

There is also an error that says Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
with the redline under the last curly brace    }

Comment: please don't make another post asking the same question, especially another post with less information than the first one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477128/error-on-overriding-a-bool-abstract-method

Comment: all you need to know is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: `public string Engine()` is not correct either. There are a lot of mistakes in your code. I recommend going through some book and learning some of the basics of C#. I think you really wanted `public class Engine` and you have a extra `}` after the engine line.

Comment: well in Visual Studio it says I need a     }     after the {  but that worked taking out the parenthesis after     public class Engine      and then removing that extra     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare an `abstract` function it can not have a body.

```
public abstract bool IsDead();
```

If you want code inside the function you must declare the function `virtual` instead of `abstract`

```
public virtual bool IsDead()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Does it still run  Yes or No")
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I still have the same error after I remove the functions below the    public abstract bool IsDead();

Comment: Well you need to [edit your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18477591/edit) and include the entire class then because there is no way I can help you without the rest of the code.